# cabal build --ghc-options="-fforce-recomp -Wall -fno-code" fails

Tags: haskell, cabal

I have some cabal failures after scaffolding my haskell project using the [holy-project](https://github.com/yogsototh/holy-project).

I don't *think* the issue is related to that plugin (seems more like general cabal question) because I could reproduce it starting from a standard `cabal init`. I'd be surprised if the issue is related to SublimeHaskell either as many people seem to be using it.

Here is the cabal file that was generated (I simplified/shortened it a bit):

(the holy-project generates some example source files along)

```
name:                   test-holy
version:                0.1.0.0
build-type:             Simple
cabal-version:          >=1.10

library
  exposed-modules:      TestHoly
                        , TestHoly.Swallow
                        , TestHoly.Coconut
  build-depends:        base >=4.7 && <4.8
  ghc-options:          -Wall
  hs-source-dirs:       src
  default-language:     Haskell2010
```

`cabal build` works

The following command does not work:

```
$ cabal clean && cabal configure && cabal build --ghc-options="-fforce-recomp -Wall -fno-code"

cleaning...
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring test-non-holy2-0.1.0.0...
Building test-non-holy2-0.1.0.0...
Preprocessing library test-non-holy2-0.1.0.0...
[1 of 3] Compiling TestHoly.Coconut ( src/TestHoly/Coconut.hs, nothing )
[2 of 3] Compiling TestHoly.Swallow ( src/TestHoly/Swallow.hs, nothing )
[3 of 3] Compiling TestHoly         ( src/TestHoly.hs, nothing )
[1 of 3] Compiling TestHoly.Coconut ( src/TestHoly/Coconut.hs, nothing )
[2 of 3] Compiling TestHoly.Swallow ( src/TestHoly/Swallow.hs, nothing )
[3 of 3] Compiling TestHoly         ( src/TestHoly.hs, nothing )
ar: dist/build/TestHoly.o: No such file or directory
ar: dist/build/TestHoly/Swallow.o: No such file or directory
ar: dist/build/TestHoly/Coconut.o: No such file or directory
```

From what I understand, due to the `-fno-code` flag (Omit code generation) no object files are generated hence the linker fails. Is that expected? Or should the linker not have been called?

*Why am I running that cabal command?*

As I said earlier on: I'm using SublimeText to edit my project. It fails on the project-holy generated cabal file with the following message:

```
Build FAILED

REMAINING STDERR:

Warning: the following files would be used as linker inputs, but linking is not being done: dist/build/TestHoly.dyn_o dist/build/TestHoly/Swallow.dyn_o dist/build/TestHoly/Coconut.dyn_o
ghc: no input files
Usage: For basic information, try the `--help' option.
```

Through the discussion on [SublimeHaskell#158](https://github.com/SublimeHaskell/SublimeHaskell/issues/158) I followed the suggestion by nh2 to run this cabal command directly (because it's the one used by SublimeHaskell).

I'd appreciate if someone can shed a light on this!

Version info

```
$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.18.0.5
using version 1.18.1.4 of the Cabal library

$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.8.3

$ system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType
Software:

    System Software Overview:

      System Version: OS X 10.10 (14A389)
      Kernel Version: Darwin 14.0.0
```

Comment: does it work if you pass the `-c` flag to ghc?

Comment: `cabal build --ghc-options="-c -fforce-recomp -Wall -fno-code"` gives the same problem. I checked by passing `--verbose` to cabal and the flag is being passed in the ghc command: `/usr/bin/ghc --make -fbuilding-cabal-package ... -Wall -c -fforce-recomp -Wall -fno-code`

Comment: Can you try adding `-fwrite-interface`?

Comment: sorry for late answer but it didn't work: `cabal clean && cabal configure && cabal build --ghc-options="-fforce-recomp -Wall -fno-code -fwrite-interface"`

`...
ar: dist/build/Simulator.o: No such file or directory
ar: dist/build/Simulator/Swallow.o: No such file or directory
ar: dist/build/Simulator/Coconut.o: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in cabal.

See https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/1176

If you don't pass `-fforce-recomp` you might be ok for incremental checking and only hit the error when you needed to do a clean build.

But absent that, cabal just doesn't know what to do when ghc doesn't actually compile things...